Is there a way to extract multiple grouped images/shapes from docx for use in indesign using AI?
I am trying to automate the workflow from a design perspective in extracting images from a generated report to use inside a presentation. The report is generated through a website (I cannot access the API to get the information directly) and is in pdf format. I have tried using pdf image extractors but the important images seem to be layered with text over the top which prevents them from being found using these tools.
After trying the image extractors, I have used Adobe Acrobat to convert the pdf to a docx document where these images are now in a grouped format. I can click on each one to save it as a png file, but I was hoping there was a tool or some advice on how to automate this process?
Thank you to anyone that may be able to help.

I think it's depends on what the PDFs look like and what you're trying to extract from them. Is it just bitmap images, or some vector graphics as well, or some complex schemes with images, graphics and texts. And what the result of the extraction should look look like? As raster images? As vector images?

Have you tried exporting the images directly from the PDF?
